# How to Implement ASP.NET Core Identity via Database First

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity, ef-database-first

I have a SQL Server database with ASP.NET Identity tables that was built using Entity Framework Core Code First.  I now need to use that database with another project that requires ASP.NET Identity.  What is the best approach to do and preserve existing data in the new project? The issue is how to address the AppContext : IdentityDbContext<[User Class]>?

Thank you.

Comment: I always put my data layer in a separate project because more often than not multiple apps will end up using the database. You can mostly copy your database code to another project if you need to, set-up migrations and the tooling in each project that uses the database or.. do it once in a separate project and just reference that in your apps.

Comment: I have a data access project for data and a domain project for the model.  They are included in the original solution. I'll look at this approach.  There are some model issues with DB first, but I have handled them.  Thanks.

Comment: You mentioned code-first issues -probably you know anyway - scaffold-dbcontext is handy if you want to reverse engineer your existing database. At the very least you have a clean starting point. Code-first generation can sometimes get messed up.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a database ready and you want to use it in your project, you should use Reverse Engineering.

in dotnet cli you can use this Command:

dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Chinook" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer

or in VS:

Scaffold-DbContext 'Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Chinook' Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer

[reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding?tabs=vs)

Comment: The reverse engineering produces a DBContext as opposed to a IdentityDbContext<[UserClass]> that is used by ASP.NET Identity.  How can I integrate the generated model with Identity?  I can't seem to find any references to this issue.  Reverse engineering does not produce a [UserClass].  The AspNetUser class produced does contain the properties from the original UserClass. This reference, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.entityframeworkcore.identitydbcontext?view=aspnetcore-5.0 , seems to imply the UserClass is not needed, but I'm not sure.